# What's the idiomatic way to do this Java function in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I'm replicating this Java function into Clojure.

```
Config createConfig(Map<String, String> options) {
  Config conf = new Config();
  String foo = options.get("foo");
  if (foo != null) { conf.setFoo(foo); }
  String bar = options.get("bar");
  if (bar != null) { conf.setBar(bar); }
  // many other configs
  return conf;
}
```

I came up with this,

```
(defn create-config [options]
  (let [conf (Config.)]
    (when-let [a (:foo options)] (.setFoo a))
    (when-let [a (:bar options)] (.setBar a))
    conf))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
(defn create-config [{:keys (foo bar)}]
  (let [config (Config.)]
    (when foo (.setFoo config foo))
    (when bar (.setBar config bar))))
```

Probably better would be to create a generic macro that can set any number of fields on an object based on a Clojure map. This could be prettier, but it works:

```
(defmacro set-fields 
  [options obj]
  (let [o (gensym)
        m (gensym)]
    `(let [~m ~options
           ~o ~obj]
       ~@(map (fn [[field value]]
                (let [setter (symbol (str "set" (clojure.string/capitalize (name field))))]
                  `(. ~o (~setter ~value))))
               options)
       ~o)))

;; call like:
(set-fields {:daemon true :name "my-thread"} (Thread.))

;; translates to:
;; (let [G__1275 {:daemon true, :name "my-thread"} 
;;       G__1274 (Thread.)]
;;   (. G__1274 (setDaemon true))
;;   (. G__1274 (setName "my-thread"))
;;   G__1274)
```

I'm not checking for null as this only looks at exactly what is passed in the options.

Comment: I like your `create-config`. It looks good enough to me. The macro was a bit overkill to me because of `clojure.string/capitalize`. Thanks!

Comment: The macro is definitely overkill if you are doing this once. But if you're doing it many times, it might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

maybe checkout [some->>](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some->>)

fillertext fillertext